# JavaFX TextField Formatting

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to have my TextField display a dollar sign at the front of my TextField, but not allow the user to delete it?

[image]

I want this display, but the user to have no way of removing the dollar sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) that filters out any changes to the text that do not result in something beginning with a `$` sign:

```
TextField purchaseCostField = new TextField("$");
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = change -> {
    if (change.getControlNewText().startsWith("$")) {
        return change ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
};
TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(filter);
purchaseCostField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

You could take this further and only allow valid input for a currency, by adding additional logic to the filter.

Comment: do you know any resource online that goes in depth on this, my textbook and stuff I found online doesnt really touch on this. Also thanks for the response

Comment: No, not really. I just pretty much learn by reading the Javadocs and looking for sample code online. (I may have more general Java experience, though.) Text formatter was introduced quite late (1.8.0 update 40 IIRC), so it isn't covered in depth in many places. (Also, please [mark the answer as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answers your question.) There are quite a few Q/A [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+TextFormatter) that talk about this, too.

Comment: have to wait 3 mins but will do once I get a chance to